# Baire category theorem dense subsets

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading John B. Conway's book on point-set topology and there the Baire category theorem is stated as follows:

> If $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space and $\{U_n\}$ is a sequence of open subsets of $X$ each of which is dense, then $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n$ is dense.

Does this mean that the subsets are dense in $X$ or in some subset of
$X$ and why is their intersection always nonempty? For example
$\mathbb Q\cap\mathbb R\setminus\{\mathbb Q\}=\emptyset$ and they are
both dense in $\mathbb R$?

Of course this is not an infinite sequence
of subsets but to me it feels like pointing to the direction that the
intersection might be empty. The proof uses the fact that the
intersection is nonempty.

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ are dense, but they aren’t open.

Comment: A subspace $U\subset \mathbb R$ is open and dense if and only if $\mathbb R\setminus U$ is closed and contains no open interval.

Comment: Ok, is there an example of an open and dense subset of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Pueti: Many examples: $\Bbb R$; $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$; $\Bbb R\setminus F$ for any finite $F\subseteq\Bbb R$; $\Bbb R\setminus C$, where $C$ is the middle-thirds Cantor set; $\Bbb R\setminus\left(\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\right)$.

Comment: $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\},$ $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Z.$ $\mathbb R\setminus C$ where $C$ is the Cantor set. As you can see, it is easier to define such sets in terms of the complement.

Comment: But it is useful to notice that these example have “small” complements. The examples have complements which are measure zero. So in some sense, the examples are “most of” the real line.

Comment: Ok thanks! Still, i don't feel clear on why the intersection of these sets is always nonempty.  Is it because if the intersection would be empty,  there would have to be an open and dense subset with measure zero, which is not possible?

Comment: If you have a couple of open sets (which you see in the comments $\mathbb Q, \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ aren't) you can extend to an infinite sequence by repeating them. So if you found even a finite number of open sets that contradicted the theorem you would have cause for concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments about, $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ are dense, but they are not open.

It is easier to characterize the complement $V$ of open dense subset of $\mathbb R.$

$V\subseteq\mathbb R$ is closed and contains no open interval if and only if $\mathbb R\setminus V$ is open and dense.

Examples of such $V:$

- finite sets
- the Cantor set
- $\mathbb Z,$ or any discrete subspace
- $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbb Z^+\right\}$

Such sets tend to be “small” in comparison  with the whole set. These examples are all measure zero, for example. The general case might not have a measure, but the theorem essentially gives another way of saying such sets are “small.”

---

Another way to state the theorem is if $\{V_i\}$ is a countable set of closed sets, none of which contains an open ball, the their union does not contain an open ball.

Comment: Ok thanks getting clearer! One last thing, in the theorem, when we are talking about the intersection being dense, what is the set it is dense in? I suppose it is the original set $X$, but whenever i've seen a visual explanation for the theorem people always draw smaller and smaller balls inside the intersections and this seems somehow wrong, as the intersection is supposed to be dense.

Comment: @pueti definitely dense in $X.$

Comment: Ok great then it makes sense. Thank you for taking the time to help!